# Event Triggers in WPF binding doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a problem with WPF Event Triggers:

in my xaml i got an arrow:

```
<Path Data="{Binding Path=Points, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=pointCollectionConverter}}"
              Stroke="Black"
              MinWidth="1"
              MinHeight="1"
              Name="arrowPath"
              StrokeThickness="2">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ArrowPathMouseLeftButtonDownCommand}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Path>
```

The Events are getting triggered as expected and everything is fine. Now i got some `Ellypses` (within the same xaml) which should behave just like the arrow on mouse right click.

So I added to my xaml for the Ellypses the Trigger part:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <controls:DragCanvas AllowDragOutOfView="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse  Cursor="Hand"
                          Fill="Black"
                          Stroke="Black"
                          StrokeThickness="2"
                          Width="10"
                          Height="10"
                          Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=endPointTrimmer}}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand}"
                                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                        Value="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                        Value="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

But I'm getting a binding error:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand' property not found on 'object' ''ConnectionPoint' (HashCode=54168362)'. BindingExpression:Path=ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand; DataItem='ConnectionPoint' (HashCode=54168362); target element is 'EventToCommand' (HashCode=42719917); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

and i dont understand why. Pleaseanyone help me

Comment: Does your `ConnectionPoint` class have a public property called `ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand`?

Comment: no, my viewmodel holds this property. But i dont understand why its looking for this property in my connectionpoint class, when the other trigger looks in my viewmodel.

Comment: What is the data type of the `Points` property that you are binding to in `ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"`?

Comment: Points is of type ObservableCollection<ConnectionPoint>

Comment: That explains why the Binding is looking for this property in your ConnectionPoint class and not in the viewmodel. I guess something like `{Binding Path=DataContext.ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand, ElementName=itemsCtrl}` could work, if you give your ItemsControl the `x:Name="itemsCtrl"` property.

Comment: thank you its working fine. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to gain access to the same ViewModel (i.e. data context) as the `ItemsControl`, you have to give your items control a name, e.g. like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsCtrl" ...>
```

and then you can use the following binding to access the `ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand` property in the ViewModel:

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand, ElementName=itemsCtrl}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use Ancestor Relative Source Binding.
like

```
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ArrowPathMouseRightButtonDownCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                    Mode=FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType=Path}}"
                                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
```

Comment: This wont work because the ancestor of the path and the ItemsControl is a Grid. Can i set type to grid and set the source to second path within that grid?

Comment: you can refer the link http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/12/7th-day-of-silverlight-ancestor-relative-source-binding/